# space character / streamwriter problem C#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I tried to make a fixed width file, but I found that when I use the space character I have a strange signs in my txt file. If I change the "50" number to something like "15" or "1000", it works fine.

This is my code:

```
string fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + "temp.txt";
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write("1".PadRight(50, ' '));
writer.Write("0".PadRight(756, ' '));
writer.Close();
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what is the result you expect ? what is the result you get ? what encoding do you need ? ASCII ? UTF8 ? UTF16 ? With/without BOM ?

Comment: What does "I have a strange signs in my txt file" mean? Please post specifically what you expect to happen and what really happens.

Comment: How do you detect those "strange signs" ? It could be just your editor/viewer not recognizing the encoding.

Comment: Is this a case of Notepad mistaking the encoding?  I remember a trick where you could type a phrase into notepad, save it, reopen it, and it would be gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard what you read here previously.  I took the output of your program, which does shows up strange in Microsoft Notepad, and opened it in a few other editors.  It appears fine in all of them.  Convinced it was some encoding error, I then cracked open XVI32 to look at the binary.

I removed a single space from the end of the file and I re-save the file and it shows up fine.    I put it back in and the problem returned.  I change the first hex character from 32 to anything less than 30 and it works fine.

So this seems like a very bizarre error with Microsoft Notepad.

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Henk What OS did you test it on?  Was it XP or a later Windows product?